# Giving eventhandler to a customized code behind generated button

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hello everyone How do i give my button a eventhanlder 
b2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(BtnChiefAns);
I tried that and it didnt work

My button is a customized button 
This is the code to call it

ButtonLeft b2 = new ButtonLeft();

and when i do this 
b2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(BtnChiefAns);
It would highlight the Click word and say unknown member 'Click' Of '"customized user control"'

This is the code behind of my customized button

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:edc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Drawing"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Volunteer.LayoutRootControl" Height="127" Width="200">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle8" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <edc:Callout AnchorPoint="0.85,1.19" CalloutStyle="Rectangle" Fill="#FFE054EF" FontSize="14.666999816894531" Stroke="Black"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Height="96" Width="196"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle8}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="197" Margin="-40,-34,-41,-32">
            <TextBlock Width="196" x:Name="BtnIN3" Text="" FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0,0,-12" Height="95" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I need to be able to click this button :( Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a UserControl, it does not have a Click event. You need to implement it.

In the code for the UserControl, add the following:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Click;
```

And then, hook the click event for the Button you have in XAML and in the implementation, write something like the following:

```
if (Click != null)
{
  Click(this, e); // Where "e" is the parameter you got from the button.
}
```

Comment: TransformBoy, if I did not understand your question, can you please explain what the problem is? I can hardly help or understand the issue with a string if question marks.

Comment: I dont know what to do with it sry

Comment: U said hook the click event for button in xaml, i dont have any button in xaml because its code generate button >.<

Comment: In XAML, you can type Click="<method name>" (the name of the method). The method will then be executed when the click occurs (and the method is in the code behind of course)

Answer (score 0):

If your `UserControl` has only one `Button`, you could create a `Button` with custom style without a `UserControl`. Then you can to create button in xaml or in this way:

```
Button b = new Button()
{
     Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ButtonStyle8"]
};
b.Click += ...
```

It will be much easier and more efficiently